# How do you get Microsoft Office Live Add-in toolbar to not show up everytime an Office App is opened?

Tags: microsoft-office, office-live

Every time I open MS Office or Excel (2003) on my machine, the Microsoft Live Add-in toolbar is there.  I remove it manually, but it always comes back.

How do I remove it permanently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to keep it from coming up unless you uninstall it completely. You can use [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) to sweep it away permanently from your machine.

Answer (score 2):

To uninstall Microsoft Office Live Add-in, follow the below mentioned steps:

1. Click “Start” and then click “Control Panel”.
2. Double-click “Add-remove Programs”.
3. In the list of currently installed programs, select Microsoft Office Live Add-in, and then click Uninstall or Remove. If a dialog box appears, follow the instructions to remove the program.
4. Click Yes or OK to confirm that you want to remove the program.

   In addition to removing ‘Microsoft Office Live Add-In’, you must remove any ‘Office Live Updates’ from your computer:
5. In the “Uninstall or change a program” dialog box, click “View installed updates” in the left pane.
6. In the list, select the updates that you want to uninstall.
7. Click “Uninstall”. Follow the instructions to remove the updates.

   Regards,